# Why is vii0 so rarely used, but V 6/5 commonplace?

Tags: chord-theory

vii0 (5/3, vii06 is more common) is almost never used in functional harmony, the reasoning being that the diminished chord creates a tritone against the bass. But V6/5, a far more common chord, has the same tritone, and is virtually the same chord. Why would vii0 be so rarely used because of the tritone, while V6/5 has the same tritone but is still used commonly?

Answer (score 1):

While this may be asking for an opinion, the predominance of V65 vs vii0 is pretty large. The root position vii0 seems to have been avoided by most composers from the Renaissance on, the vii06 was a common substitute. I'm guessing that the tritone is "interior" rather than against the base for this case.

The V65 does have a tritone against the bass though. Various theorists (Piston is one) did claim that many composers, especially from the Nineteenth Century, treated the vii07, and its minor form (I don't have a phi) were often treated as a dominant seventh with the root missing. The only place vii0 was used as itself was in sequences (preceding the iii chord in a major key.)

While the vii0 and the V65 only differ in that the V65 has a sounding scale step 5 (no carets for numerals either, not even in Unicode). Perhaps the combination of avoiding vii0 in general and having the putative root sound made the V65 more useful. (Or at least better sounding to composers.)

Comment: what is "minor form of vii07"?

Comment: @user1079505 - Based on the "I don't have a phi" remark, I assume the "minor form of vii07" is actually vii half-diminished 7th.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't have a website so I cannot connect to pictures. Perhaps sometime in the future. I'd still like to have a "music" font  (even the text part.) My point was that the V65 contains the root and that vii0 wasn't popular even in pre-chordal days; vii6 was though (the dissonant interval was not sounding against the bass but this idea doesn't directly apply to the V65.)